# unexpected bug in conversion between std::chrono::duration with different Rep

Tags: c++11

I noticed unexpected behaviour and narrowed it down to conversion from one duration to another.

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using sec = std::chrono::seconds;
using fsec = std::chrono::duration<float>;
using dsec = std::chrono::duration<double>;

template<typename T>
auto count_intervals(T time_jump) -> uint32_t
{
  constexpr auto interval = sec(10);
  std::cout << "[debug] " << time_jump.count() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "[debug] " << interval.count() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "[debug] " << time_jump.count() / interval.count() << std::endl;
  printf("[debug] %.10f\n", time_jump.count());
  printf("[debug] %.10f\n", time_jump.count() / interval.count());
  const uint32_t k = std::ceil(time_jump.count() / interval.count());
  std::cout << "[debug] " << k << std::endl;
  return k;
}

int main()
{
  using clock_t = std::chrono::system_clock;
  using time_point_t = typename clock_t::time_point;
  using std::chrono::duration_cast;

  const auto start_point = time_point_t();
  const auto a = start_point + sec(25);
  const auto b = start_point + sec(55);

  std::cout << count_intervals<fsec>(b - a) << std::endl;
  std::cout << count_intervals<fsec>(duration_cast<fsec>(b - a)) << std::endl;
  const auto distance = duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<uint32_t>>(b - a);
  std::cout << count_intervals<fsec>(distance) << std::endl;
  std::cout << count_intervals<dsec>(b - a) << std::endl;
}
```

I cannot figure out why `std::ceil` rounds up. It seems when I use `dsec` instead of `fsec` all is fine. The question is what is my mistake in case of `float` duration representation. I thought I use `std::chrono::duration` as intended but obviously that is not the case. How should I perform conversion to `fsec` correctly? In general I would like to have a fraction-of-a-second duration format.

output

```
[debug] 30
[debug] 10
[debug] 3
[debug] 30.0000019073
[debug] 3.0000002384
[debug] 4
4
[debug] 30
[debug] 10
[debug] 3
[debug] 30.0000019073
[debug] 3.0000002384
[debug] 4
4
[debug] 30
[debug] 10
[debug] 3
[debug] 30.0000000000
[debug] 3.0000000000
[debug] 3
3
[debug] 30
[debug] 10
[debug] 3
[debug] 30.0000000000
[debug] 3.0000000000
[debug] 3
3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your platform, `system_clock::time_point` is a type alias for `time_point<system_clock, nanoseconds>`.  It turns out that this detail is important.

When running the `float` version of this test, the very first step is convert `b - a` to `duration<float>` to make the call to `count_intervals`.  The type of `b - a` is `nanoseconds`.  The value of `b - a` is `30'000'000'000ns`.

It takes 25 bits of precision to store the integer `30'000'000'000`.  IEEE float has 24 bits of precision.

The first step in converting `30'000'000'000ns` to `duration<float>` is store the number `30'000'000'000` into the `common_type` of `system_clock::rep` and `float` which is `float`.  It can only do this approximately.  It actually stores `30'000'001'024`, which is the best representable value under the "round toward nearest, and to even on tie" policy.  It then divides this approximation by `1'000'000'000` (stored in a `float`), and gets approximately `30`.  The exact value it gets is `0x1.e00002p+4`, or `30.000001...`

From here on out, the computation is slightly off from exact.

You can see this for yourself by setting `cout` to `hexfloat` mode which will output floating point numbers exactly:

```
std::cout << std::hexfloat;
```

And/or, set precision to 15 (or so):

```
std::cout.precision(15);
```

The computation works as you expect with `duration<double>` because `double` has 53 bits of precision and can thus store `30'000'000'000` exactly.